# If I trade a 100 IV pokémon, will it's IV levels change, or will they stay the same?

Tags: pokemon-go

I am trading a 100 IV pokémon from my alternate account to my main account, because I have lots of candies on my main account.

If I trade a 100 IV pokémon, will it's IV levels change, or will they stay the same?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/334553/143571

Answer (score 0):

From [Pokemon GO Hub](https://pokemongohub.net/post/guide/a-comprehensive-guide-to-pokemon-go-trading-mechanics-and-rules/):

> IVs, HP and CP change when trading, but moves, gender and size of the traded Pokemon stay the same. Be careful: Pokemon Level can also change!